# Xamarin Android: Resource.designer Id does not match Android component Id

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to find an ImageView within the SearchView widget, the ImageView's Id name is *search_close_btn*. I'm looking it up with this line of code however it returns null.

`closeButton = searchView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.search_close_btn);`

I investigated the children of the search view and found the ImageView and discovered that the Id of the child did not match the one from the designer.

I'm curious to where the correct Id is stored as I have to search the view manually in order to find it.
Is java's R.Id the equivalent to Xamarin's Resource.Id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following once you have a reference to your SearchView:

```
 int searchPlateId = searchView.Context.Resources.GetIdentifier("android:id/search_plate", null, null);
 View searchPlate = searchView.FindViewById(searchPlateId); 
 if (searchPlate != null)
 {
      int imgViewId = searchPlate.Context.Resources.GetIdentifier("android:id/search_close_btn", null, null);
      ImageView imgView = (ImageView)searchPlate.FindViewById(imgViewId);
      if (imgView != null)
    {
           Console.WriteLine("Found you image view: {0}", imgView);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is perfect. As I only need the search_close_btn, I simplified it by just doing. 
`var closeBtnId = searchView.Context.Resources.GetIdentifier("android:id/search_close_btn", null, null);
closeButton = searchView.FindViewById(closeBtnId);`